# How can I download a private Google Drive file through a simple HTTP request?

Tags: rest, http, google-drive-api

I'm making a simple CLI script that is intended to automatically download a Google Sheets spreadsheet as a CSV and convert it into other data. I quickly got lost in the weeds about how to authorize such a request.

I'm trying to use this API:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/export`

It requests an API key, which I created through the Google Cloud interface. The key is accepted as valid, but it claims that it cannot find the file. I anticipated that a Google Cloud created for a particular organization would have access to any Google Drive files that are shared to that organization, but it appears this is not the case.

My next lead was to explore so-called "service accounts" but the more I read up on that, the more it sounded like bringing a thermonuclear bomb to a fistfight. I just want to send an HTTP request and get back a `.csv`. Is that even possible?